# iOS - QuickLook returning no window subview

Tags: ios, hidden, subview, uipopover, quicklook

I try to display an FPPopover and for this I need a parentView. Everything is fine on first attempt. But after displaying a PDF in QuicklLookViewController, the number of subviews in windows is 0, so I cannot grasp the last element to use it as parentView... With a NSLog I can see that the last object of my view hierarchy is hidden, explaining probably why the count is 0. The lastObject seems to be this new kind of UITextEffectsWindow...

**FPPopoverController.m**

*Init method*

```
NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
if(windows.count > 0)
{
    _parentView=nil;
    _window = [windows lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Window.subviews count: %d", _window.subviews.count); // --> return 1 if no PDF was previously seen with QuickLook --> So popover is displayed the first time.

    //keep the first subview
    if(_window.subviews.count > 0)  // ---> subviews.count is 0 after displaying a PDF with QuickLook --> method not called the second time and popover is not displayed
    {

        _parentView = [_window.subviews lastObject];
        [_parentView addSubview:self.view];
        [_viewController viewDidAppear:YES];

        NSLog(@"windows: %@" "window: %@", _windows, _window); // --> I can see that the last element is hidden after displaying the PDF (something not present before I display PDF with QuickLook...)
        NSLog(@"Parentview: %@", _parentView);
    }
```

Any ideas why this is happening? I cannot figure out why QuickLook returns no subviews or hides them... Any way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextEffectsWindow seems to be the window hosting the keyboard. Anyway, you should refactor `FPPopover` (which is not maintained anymore) to be able to specify the parent view (and pass your view controller's view, or whatever is appropriate) instead of trying to find out a suitable one in the init method .

This kind of view hierarchy exploration is highly discouraged as remote view controllers and keyboards sometimes manipulate the window list. If you really want to discover a view to add yourself to manually, it's better to start with the root view controller's view.